# How to add entity key when database table with no primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to insert data into the database table which is has no primary key using Entity Framework.

error occurred

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT\n collection.CustomerID, collection.AmountRecevied, \n' at line 1

I posted data using fiddler,

```
{"CustomerID":"12122","AmountRecevied":"2000","Date_Time":"","longitude":"17.3660° N","AgentID":"15","Money_Receipt_No":"56654","Payment_Mode":"cash","Money_Receipt_Photo":"","latitude":"78.4760° E"}
```

Code:

```
try
{
    var vvv = cs.collections.Select(x => x.CustomerID).ToList();
    cs.collections.Add(collection);
    cs.SaveChanges();
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
return true;

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(collection Collection)
{
        if (Collection == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "not created");

        if (obj.PostUser(Collection))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, TheModelFactory.create(Collection));
        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save to the database");
}
```

Properties

```
public partial class collection
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountRecevied { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Time { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AgentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Money_Receipt_No { get; set; }
    public string Payment_Mode { get; set; }
    public byte[] Money_Receipt_Photo { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You **must** add a **primary key** to your table. Period. Every "serious" table (except maybe temporary, staging table) **ought to have** a primary key!

Comment: cannot we add key for entites?

Comment: can I use this http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-adding-datatable-with.html?

Comment: I personally wouldn't try to *hack* or *kludge* this - just update your table with a **primary key** which any table should have in the first place, and then all your troubles go away!